# PHP: How to handle uploading 2 files and output

Tags: php, image-uploading

Good day!

I will start by saying I am just starting to learn PHP, so take it easy on me...

Basically, I have a form that allows users to upload 2 images (along with completing other fields).  On submit, the form calls a PHP file (code below) which basically adds the details to a database and uploads the images to a file server.  This is working fine for what I am trying to accomplish.  Where I am having trouble is with the confirmation message.

Since I have 2 separate upload fields, I basically have 2 if statements that confirm the two files have been uploaded properly.  I'd like to streamline this a bit so I really only have to display 1 confirmation message.

Any ideas on how I can streamline this?  I am thinking the code will look if both files were uploaded successfully, if so echo "x", else echo "y".  I am less familiar with the move_uploaded_file function so I am not sure if I can user AND statements there...  Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

```
//This is the directory where images will be saved
$target = "path/";
$target = $target . basename($_FILES[controlcreative][name]);
$target2 = "path/";
$target2 = $target2 . basename($_FILES[winnercreative][name]);

$pic=($_FILES['controlcreative']['name']);
$pic2=($_FILES['winnercreative']['name']);

$con=mysqli_connect();
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="INSERT INTO experiments (vertical, pagetype, pagename, primarykpitype, primarykpilift, primarysignificant, testobjective, takeawayone, optimizationtype, controlcreative, winnercreative)
VALUES
('$_POST[vertical]','$_POST[pagetype]','$_POST[pagename]','$_POST[primarykpitype]','$_POST[primarykpilift]','$_POST[primarysignificant]','$_POST[testobjective]','$_POST[takeawayone]','$_POST[optimizationtype]','$pic','$pic2')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "1 record added";


//Writes the photo to the server
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES[controlcreative][tmp_name], $target))
{

//Tells you if its all ok
echo "The file ". basename($_FILES[controlcreative][name]). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";
}
else {

//Gives and error if its not
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}

//Writes the photo to the server
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES[winnercreative][tmp_name], $target2))
{

//Tells you if its all ok
echo "The file ". basename($_FILES[winnercreative][name]). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";
}
else {

//Gives and error if its not
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}


mysqli_close($con);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd loop through `$_FILES` which might save you some code and set an error flag

```
$error = false;
foreach($_FILES as $name => $file)
{
    $target = '/path/to/destination/' . $file['name'];
    if(!move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $target)) $error = true;
}
```

Then

```
if(!$error) echo 'All files uploaded';
```

Comment: I actually worked out the answer...thanks for the assistance though. `if((move_uploaded_file($_FILES[controlcreative][tmp_name], $target)) && move_uploaded_file($_FILES[winnercreative][tmp_name], $target2))`